# How are function metrics aggregated over batches in tensorflow model validation?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In tensorflow `tf.keras.Model.compile`, you can pass a `lambda y_true, y_pred: val` function as a metric (though, it seems not documented), but I asked my self : "How does it aggregate it over the batches" ?

I searched the documentation, but I've found nowhere how it is done ?

By the way, I don't even know if it is an undefined behavior to do so and one should instead subclass the Metric class ? ( or at least provide the required methods).

Also, is it pertinent to pass a loss as a metric (and in this case, same question : how is it aggregated over the batches ? )

Answer (score 0):

To understand "How does it aggregate (I'm assuming for display in the progress bar)", I suggest you check `tf.keras.utils.Progbar`. Aggregation over batches is done when you use `model.fit`, not `model.compile`.

Is using a `lambda` as a loss or metric undefined behaviour? `No, if defined properely`. If you do not write the lambda expression properly, TensorFlow will throw an Exception.

Is using a `lambda` as a loss or metric recommended? `Nope`. There is a reason TensorFlow provides separate classes for these. Extending inbuilt classes simplifies other parts of the pipeline, such as saving or loading models. It also makes the code much more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, it is not for doing a progress bar, it's mainly to be sure about what value is reported. I think the best thing is to define a custom metric implementing the update method, so that I have a full control on the calculation :)

Answer (score 0):

It should just take the average over batches. I don't think it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Creating Custom Metrics" section [here](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#creating-custom-metrics). The metric you use (the lambda) is a stateless, and therefore, during training, it's

> the average of the per-batch metric values for all batches seen during a given epoch.